# 論理的凝集がわかりません

Tags: javascript

https://github.com/PandaNoir/RabbitPlot/blob/master/js/calendar.js
例えば上のコード中のexecSelector()は論理的凝集ですか?
execSelector()は、date:3やmonth:mayと言ったセレクターを処理してその結果を返します。
date:3かmonth:mayかはswitchで切り替えていて、処理はそれぞれ独立したものになっています。
もし、論理的凝集ならどう解決したらいいのか、論理的凝集でないなら論理的凝集のわかりやすい説明が欲しいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

論理的凝集の例を調べるレポートか何かでしょうか？

凝集度はモジュールに対して評価されるものなので、単一の関数が凝集度が高いか低いか、というのは言えないと思います。
calendar.js全体に関して言えば、ぱっと見はカレンダーに関する処理が集まっているので機能的凝集だと言えると思います。

Comment: なるほど、どうやら凝集度を勘違いしていたようです。理解出来ました。